# Сменить все ссылки http на https

Tags: javascript, jquery, opencart

знатоки.

Возникла проблема. Нужно через JS код поменять все ссылки(в `<imt>` и `<a>` и других) с http://*путь* на https://*путь*.

Платформа OpenCart и ссылка уже создана на моменте, когда нужно поменять.

Подскажите, какой скрипт написать и куда его вставить.

Заранее спасибо!

Answer (score 2):

Не знаю, почему именно через JS ?

Если так, то надо включить этот скрипт на всех страницах, где нужно обновить ссылки:

```
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js" ></script>

<script type="text/javaScript">
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("a").each(function() {
    var i = $(this).attr("href");
    var n = i.replace("http://", "https://");
    $(this).attr("href", function() {
      return n;
    })
  })
});
</script>
```

Если у вас jquery уже подключен, первую строку пропустите.

Comment: Встречный вопрос, почему JQ, а не JS? Зачем ради этой фигни тянуть целую библиотеку?

Comment: Просто насколько я знаю Опенкарте используется jquery. Почему бы не использовать раз она включен. Если нет то переписать 5 минут займет.

Answer (score 0):

Вариант на чистом JS:

```js
document.querySelectorAll('[href^="http:"')
    .forEach(el => {el.href = el.href.replace(/^http/, 'https')});
document.querySelectorAll('[src^="http:"')
    .forEach(el => {el.src = el.src.replace(/^http/, 'https')});
```